# How can I connect a 3 wire RTD to a 2 wire system

Tags: thermocouple

I received a thermocouple replacement part from a machinery company. It has 3 wires (white, black, green/yellow), but the thermocouple it is replacing only has 2 wires (white, red). Can I use the white and black connections of the 3 wire RTD for the white and red connections and leave the green/yellow leg floating? If not, what is the correct way to connect this?

Comment: Nevermind. Green/yellow is ground. This is a grounded thermocouple. I am dumb.

Comment: Suggest post this as an answer to your own question, then select it as the accepted answer.  Cheers.

Comment: If you have resolved you problem through research, it would be good to post a clear answer with your understanding if the solution, and then accept the answer. If you can link to a web references on the topic, even better.

Comment: Those are strange color codes for the replacement thermocouple. White and red would be Iron/Constantan in North American (ISA) color code (red being negative, of course). Not sure what your replacement would be..

Comment: It's a thermocouple used on a German injection molding machine. Unfortunately when the company mailed me the replacement, they didn't include a part number or anything I could look up for a datasheet. I can ask them for it, but they're not super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Classic 3-wire RTD have two wires the same colour, and one different (two red, one white or two black, one white are common).  One of the same colour wires is used to inject the measurement current, the other provides a partial Kelvin sense to allow compensation for cable losses.

4-wire has two of each colour, and allows full Kelvin sensing.

The cables can also be provided with a shield, and the sensing element may also be enclosed in a grounded metal case.  This may be exposed at the connection end, either as a bare wire, or as a "ground" yellow/green connection.  In both cases this wire is normally isolated from the sensing element.